# MySQL Limit from 10th to 20th

Tags: mysql, limit

How can i use LIMIT when i want to start at 10th row and go until 20th row?
I have

`SELECT * FROM approved_servers WHERE TIP=0 LIMIT NUMBER1, NUMBER2`

What numbers are here from 10th-20th row?

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT ... LIMIT [OFFSET], [HOW MANY]`

so...

<strike>`SELECT * FROM approved_servers WHERE TIP=0 LIMIT 10,10`</strike> (wrong)

`SELECT * FROM approved_servers WHERE TIP=0 LIMIT 9,10`

Comment: I am surprised no one noticed my mistake ;]

Comment: Tested right now, not working: I need return all rowse from 10th-20th rows, I have one row in 11th but 10,10 numbers doesnt return this row.

Comment: @user3347305 yeah check my edit :) `limit 0,10` will gives you rows 1st-10th, `limit 9,10` gives you rows 10th-20th

Comment: no u was right :D 10,10 works but item in table (11th) has TIP=0 but when i put in command WHERE TIP=0 it doesnt return this item, but i when i remove WHERE TIP=0 it return this item. :(

Comment: @user3347305 check again ;]